# Displaying current username in _Layout view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am wanting to display the current ApplicationUsers Firstname+Lastname on my navigation bar on my _Layout view. I've found that you can pass your viewbag from the current RenderedBody controller like so:

```
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContext;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly ApplicationUser _user;

    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager) {
       _httpContext = httpContextAccessor;
       _userManager = userManager;
        _user = _userManager.Users.Single(u => u.Id == _httpContext.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value);
    }
```

And in a controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
    {

        ViewBag.Username = $"{_user.FirstName} {_user.Surname}";
        return View();
    }
```

Finally in my _Layout View:

```
<strong class="font-bold">@ViewBag.Username</strong>
```

This method seems like it's going against the grain and would be a huge pain to do for every view. What would be the standard in achieving this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can inject the `UserManager` and `SignInManager` in to your view.

```
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager
```

Then you can test if user login with `SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User)` and show user name with `UserManager.GetUserName(User)`

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
  <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li>
     <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log off</button>
    </li>
   </ul>
 </form>
}
```

PS. Also you need to add these two `using` as well

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using MyWebApp.Models
```

Comment: Ah, that's perfect! Simple and efficient. Thanks heaps, Ahmar.

Comment: Happy to help you. :)

Comment: None of this works in my Asp.net MVC project in Visual Studio 2017. Doesn't know what @inject is, not sure if this is because it's EntityFrameWork and not Core. .NET 4.7

Comment: That was great, I added the above to the _Layout.cshtml page and it worked. I am using Razor Pages with .Net 6.0.3

Answer (score 3):

For an ASP.Core Razor page, inject the UserManager into _Layout.cshtml

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using webApp.Models
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager
@{
    Layout = "/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var displayName = user.DisplayName;
    var imagePath = user.GravatarImageUrl;
}

<h1>Manage your account</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Change your account settings</h4>
    <hr />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <img src="@imagePath" alt="Avatar" />
            <h4>@displayName</h4>
            <partial name="_ManageNav" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An updated answer, 
in your `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@using System.Security.Claims
@using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

@inject IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor
@{
    string name = 
       httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get any information from your **extended User** (ApplicationUser):

```
// Inject SignInManager and UserManager in your _Layout.cshtml
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager;
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;


 @if (signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
                {
                   // Get the current logged in user
                    Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

                    var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();

                    var firstName = user.FirstName;
                    var lastName = user.LastName;
                    var lastLogin = user.LastLogin;
                    var nationality = user.Nationality;
                    var phoneNumber = user.PhoneNumber;

                    <h4>@firstName @lastName</h4>                                                                     
                    <h4>@lastLogin</h4>                                                
                    <h4>@nationality</h4>                                                
                    <h4>@phoneNumber</h4>
                }
```